# serialize HybridDictionary to byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I wrote below code

```
HybridDictionary state = new HybridDictionary();

using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(buffer , state);


                _backup.Push(buffer .ToArray());

            }
```

but I got error  on formatter.serialize(st,state) as below  :

"
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Type 'System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor' in Assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable."

what does it mean ?

Comment: What is the content of the dictionary, iow keys and values?

Comment: name ofthe entity + name of the filed and value of the field

Comment: Does the value type include that PropertyDescriptor? It sounds like a BindingList/BindingSource perhaps.

Comment: I got current item of the bindingsource and read fields of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
[field:NonSerializedAttribute()]
public event MyEventHandler SomeEvent;
```

to your events. This will omit them from serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid serializing the registered event handlers on your events (As you state in the comment to the previous answer your objects do have events). If one of the registered handlers would not be serializable, this whould throw and exception.

The idea stems from a [Forum post on Sanity Free dot org](http://www.sanity-free.org/113/csharp_binary_serialization_oddities.html).

Here's how I have implemented this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a property value changes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <devdoc>Do not serialize this delegate, since we do not want to have
    /// the event listener persisted.</devdoc>
    [NonSerialized]
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a property value changes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Effectively, this is fired whenever the wrapped MapXtreme theme 
    /// of the AssociatedTheme property gets changed
    /// via the MapXtreme API.</remarks>
    /// <devdoc>The implementation using the public event and the private delegate is
    /// to avoid serializing the (probably non-serializable) listeners to this event.
    /// see http://www.sanity-free.org/113/csharp_binary_serialization_oddities.html
    /// for more information.
    /// </devdoc>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        add
        {
            _propertyChanged = (PropertyChangedEventHandler)Delegate.Combine(_propertyChanged, value);
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        remove
        {
            _propertyChanged = (PropertyChangedEventHandler)Delegate.Remove(_propertyChanged, value);
        }
    }
```

Best Regards, Marcel

Comment: If that entity class you mention, is put in the dictionary, then yes. 

But, also have a look at the previous answer (by Mikael Svenson), as he apparently seems to do the same thing as I propose, but in a much simpler way. I however, have not tested his solution. Give him credit if his solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error says, you have System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor in your dictionary and it is not marked as serializable.

Comment: After I got field information from object as below code:

'
 fields = sourceType.GetFields(
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Instance );
'
I found that two event information got into " fields " 
how can I change above code for getting just value fields not event fields ?